# Make toggle from left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello i have the following HTML:

```
<span class="slide1"><a href="#" class="slide1">Behavior</a></span>
<div id="second" class="content1">I’m not a good</div>
```

And the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#second').hide();
    $('span.slide1').click(function () {
        $('#second').slideToggle(800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I make the hidden div toggle and show from the left side?

I mean when I click the element I want the div to appear to the left of the span element.

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/70/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the effect like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/70/

```
<span id="second" class="content1" style="width:0px; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; float: left; white-space:nowrap;">I’m not a good</span>

<a href="#" class="slide1" style="float: left;">Behavior</a>

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.slide1').click(function () {
           $('#second').animate({
               width: '100px',
           }, 1000);
       });
   });
```

Comment: why it is not hidding when i click again? it should do that

Comment: @Chris The Fiddle in your answer is the same as the fiddle in the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do this, one that also requires jQuery UI, the other with only jQuery.

**Without jQuery UI:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#second').hide();
     $('span.slide1').click(function () {
         $('#second').animate({width:'toggle'},800);;
         return false;
     });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gVjFs/75/)**. This example uses .animate() to change the width.

---

**With jQuery UI**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#second').hide();
     $('span.slide1').click(function () {
         $('#second').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 800);
         return false;
     });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gVjFs/74/)**. This example uses jQuery UI's effects methods.

Comment: +1 as your first example is doing a toggle both ways, in and back out. Add to that some nice CSS to prevent the wrapping of the text and it's perfect. `#second{ white-space: nowrap; }` - [**With CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/78/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need some CSS style to do this.

```
.slide1 {
    display:inline-block;
}
.content1{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is the [updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/71/)

Cheers.

**EDIT:** Just read again the answer and it looks you want it to appear on the left, sorry about the previous, but with css you can do it fine as well

```
.slide1 {
    display:inline-block;
}
.content1{
    float:left;
}
```

[New JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/76/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. You will need `effects` from `jquery-ui`, but as i can see in your jsfiddle, you are using it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#second').hide();
    $('span.slide1').click(function () {
        $('#second').effect('slide', 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/73/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
.slide1 {
display:inline-block;
}
.content1{
display:inline-block;
float: left;
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/gVjFs/77/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom animation, like this one:

```
jQuery.fn.blindToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
  var h = this.outerWidth();
  return this.show().animate({marginLeft: parseFloat(this.css('marginLeft')) < 0 ? 0 : -h}, speed, easing, callback);  
};
```